# Julia - LoadError on worker with function in the file (main)

Tags: parallel-processing, julia, multicore

I am starting trying to use Julia for parallel processing.

I am using the `@spawn` macro in this example, but had the same error using the `remotecall_fetch` function.

Following is the code:

```
function count_proteins(fpath::String)
    cnt::Int = 0
    if !isfile(fpath)
        write(Base.stderr, "FASTA not found!")
    else
        reader = open(FASTA.Reader, fpath)
        for record in reader
            cnt += 1
        end
    end
    # return the count
    cnt
end


"""Count sequences in parallel."""
function parallel_count_proteins(fPaths::Array{String, 1}, threads::Int16=4)    
    # initialize workers
    addprocs(threads)

    fut = Dict{Int, Future}()

    # launch the jobs
    for (i, fastaPath) in enumerate(fPaths)
        r = @spawn count_proteins(fastaPath)
        fut[i] = r
    end

    for (i, res) in fut
        s = fetch(res)
    end
end

### MAIN ###
flist = ["f1", "f2", "f3", "f4"]
threads = Int16(2)
parallel_count_proteins(flist, threads)
```

The error happens when I try to fetch the results using `fetch()`:

> ERROR: LoadError: On worker 3

...and here is the stacktrace:

```
Stacktrace:
 [1] #remotecall_fetch#149(::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::Function, ::Function, ::Distributed.Worker, ::Distributed.RRID) at /Users/osx/buildbot/slave/package_osx64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/Distributed/src/remotecall.jl:379
 [2] remotecall_fetch(::Function, ::Distributed.Worker, ::Distributed.RRID, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at /Users/osx/buildbot/slave/package_osx64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/Distributed/src/remotecall.jl:371
 [3] #remotecall_fetch#152 at /Users/osx/buildbot/slave/package_osx64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/Distributed/src/remotecall.jl:406 [inlined]
 [4] remotecall_fetch at /Users/osx/buildbot/slave/package_osx64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/Distributed/src/remotecall.jl:406 [inlined]
 [5] call_on_owner at /Users/osx/buildbot/slave/package_osx64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/Distributed/src/remotecall.jl:479 [inlined]
 [6] fetch(::Future) at /Users/osx/buildbot/slave/package_osx64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/Distributed/src/remotecall.jl:511
 [7] parallel_count_proteins(::Array{String,1}, ::Int16) at /Users/salvocos/Google_Drive/julia_programming/mcl_graph_to_label.jl:150
 [8] top-level scope at none:0
 [9] include at ./boot.jl:326 [inlined]
 [10] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1038
 [11] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
 [12] exec_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:267
 [13] _start() at ./client.jl:436
```

I know in need to make all the workers aware of the exstance of the function `count_proteins` but I am quite not sure on how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @hckr nicely explains above, the workers should be deployed (using addprocs(threads)) before using the `@everywhere` macro.

@everywhere can be called and used in different ways and in different parts of the program.
In my case I am loading the function that I want to run in parallel from a module.

To use this function in parallel from the main I am using `@everywhere include("myModule.jl")`.

Following are the code for MyModule:

```
module MyModule    
using Distributed
using Printf: @printf
using Base

"""Count sequences in the input FASTA"""
function count_proteins(fpath::String)::Int
    cnt::Int = 0
    #@show fpath
    if !isfile(fpath)
        write(Base.stderr, "\nInput FASTA not found!")
    else
        open(fpath, "r") do ifd
            for ln in eachline(ifd)
                if ln[1] == '>'
                    #println(ln)
                    cnt += 1
                end
            end
        end
    end
    # return the count
    @printf("%s\t%d\n", fpath, cnt)
    cnt
end

"""Count sequences in parallel."""
function parallel_count_proteins(fPaths::Array{String, 1})

    # spawn the jobs
    for (i, fastaPath) in enumerate(fPaths)
        r = @spawn count_proteins(fastaPath)
        # @show r
        s = fetch(r)
    end    
end
```

And following is the `main.jl` using the function `parallel_count_proteins` from `MyModule`.

```
### main.jl ###
using Base
using Distributed
using Printf: @printf

# add path to the modules directory
push!(LOAD_PATH, dirname(@__FILE__)) # MyModule is in the same directory as main.jl

#### MAIN START ####
# deploy the workers
addprocs(4)
# load modules with multi-core functions
@everywhere include(joinpath(dirname(@__FILE__), "MyModule.jl"))

# paths with 4 input files (all in same dir as main.jl)
flist = ["tv1", "tv2", "tv3", "tv4"]

# count proteins
MyModule.parallel_count_proteins(flist)
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you need to make `count_proteins` available to all the worker processes.

You can use [`@everywhere`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Distributed/#Distributed.@everywhere) macro before the function definitions to make them available to all the workers. `@everywhere` executes a given expression on all workers.

Another way would be to put the functions that *should be* available to workers inside another `.jl` file and `@everywhere include("my_helper_functions.jl")`, or put your function definitions inside a `begin...end` block and put an `@everywhere` right before `begin` and run the block. You need to do this after the creation of worker processes. Putting such functions inside a module/package and running `@everywhere using MyModule` should also work.

For your code the solution would be

```
# addprocs here before @everywhere definitions
addprocs(2)

@everywhere function count_proteins(fpath::String)
    cnt::Int = 0
    if !isfile(fpath)
        write(Base.stderr, "FASTA not found!")
    else
        reader = open(FASTA.Reader, fpath)
        for record in reader
            cnt += 1
        end
    end
    # return the count
    cnt
end


"""Count sequences in parallel."""
function parallel_count_proteins(fPaths::Array{String, 1})
    fut = Dict{Int, Future}()

    # launch the jobs
    for (i, fastaPath) in enumerate(fPaths)
        r = @spawn count_proteins(fastaPath)
        fut[i] = r
    end

    for (i, res) in fut
        s = fetch(res)
    end
end

### MAIN ###
flist = ["f1", "f2", "f3", "f4"]
parallel_count_proteins(flist)
```

As a side note, If I understand what you are trying to do correctly, you can simply use [`pmap`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Distributed/#Distributed.pmap) here instead, which will send the tasks one by one to processes, effectively balancing load.

You might find it useful to read [the manual entry](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/parallel-computing/#Code-Availability-and-Loading-Packages-1) regarding code and data availability in parallel computing and also the Parallel Computing section overall. For data availability part there is also a package called [`ParallelDataTransfer.jl`](https://github.com/ChrisRackauckas/ParallelDataTransfer.jl) which makes moving data between processes a lot easier if you ever need it.

Comment: Hello hckr and thanks a lot for your help.
Unluckily I keep having the same error...
I have tried the following in the following order:
1) @everywhere funtion protein_count
2) Put the main code in a module and call it from a main.jl script which calls parallel_count_proteins

The above trials did not solve the issue.

I have read the manual before posting this question...still it is not clear to me how to get it to work.

Comment: To clarify, what I am trying to do is to process a list of files in parallel.
Could you please post a working example in which  you do a similar thing?

For example, the function that should be run in parallel is in the module MyModule, and the function is called in a main.jl file.

That would really help me a lot.

Regarding data-passing, I just want to get the variable/object returned by the function performed in parallel (basically what remotecall_fetch would return).

Thank a lot for your help.

Comment: I have also tried with pmap and a get an error which is, I think, related to the same problem.


ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: count_proteins not defined

Comment: @SalvatoreCosentino You sure you executed `@everywhere count_proteins...definition...end` *after* you have created worker processes?

Comment: "@"everywhere function count_proteins" is how I define the function.

- the function "parallel_protein_function" calls count_protein using "@"spawn (or pmap). 

- addprocs(2) is called inside parallel_count_proteins

- both count_proteins and parallel_count_proteins are defined in the same modules 

- the module is loaded in main by "using mymodule: parallel_count_proteins" and then called in the main

Comment: With "after you have created worker processes" do you mean after calling addprocs() or @spawn??? 

Eitherway, \@everywhere is in afunction, separate from the function which calls it.
Sorry if it maybe simple, but I really cannot get it wok.

Comment: `addprocs(threads)` should be called *before* `@everywhere` definitions. Because `@everywhere` executes the code on available processes.  Your code does it after *calling* the `parallel_count_proteins`. You should not put this inside `parallel_count_proteins`.  Just run it in `Main` once before everything else or omit it altogether and run julia with `julia -p 2` start julia with 2 worker processes.

I just edited my answer, let's not use modules or other things this time. `addprocs` is at the beginning of the snippet if you start `julia -p 2` you can omit that line.

Comment: Thanks a lot @hckr, I have solved the problem by calling addprocs(threads) before using the `@everywhere` macro. To load from the module I am using `@everywhere include("/paths_to/my_module.jl"`).

Comment: Oddly enough I am seeing an increase in execution time when using multiple cores. I have tested using both UNIX time and the `@time` macro, but I think I will probably ask a different question about this.